# Check a materialized view exists?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

How do I check if a materialized view exists?

I have created one and checked in `information_schema.tables` and `information_schema.views`but I cannot see it.

Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the system catalog [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html), e.g.:

```
create materialized view my_view as select 1;

select relname, relkind
from pg_class
where relname = 'my_view'
and relkind = 'm';

 relname | relkind 
---------+---------
 my_view | m
(1 row)
```

or the system view [`pg_matviews`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-matviews.html)

```
select *
from pg_matviews
where matviewname = 'my_view';  

 schemaname | matviewname | matviewowner | tablespace | hasindexes | ispopulated | definition 
------------+-------------+--------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------
 public     | my_view     | postgres     |            | f          | t           |  SELECT 1;
(1 row)
```

Comment: To actually check that materialized view exists use `select count(*)` instead of simple `select *`. In case of 1 - it exists, 0 - you get the idea..

Comment: @standalone - not exactly. There may be more than one view with the same name, so rather `select count (*) > 0` (returns Boolean).